# For loop in jQuery to insert div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to insert a div that shows the Day within another div using jQuery. I HTML structure is as follows:

```
<div class="am-event-info">
 <div class="am-event-sub-info">
  <div class="am-event-sub-info-capacity"><img src=""> Capacity: 0 / 100</div>
 </div>
<div class="am-event-sub-info">
  <div><img src="">February 27th, 2021 11:30 am - 1:00 pm</div>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="am-event-info">
 <div class="am-event-sub-info">
  <div class="am-event-sub-info-capacity"><img src=""> Capacity: 0 / 100</div>
 </div>
<div class="am-event-sub-info">
  <div><img src="">February 28th, 2021 11:30 am - 1:00 pm</div>


 </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to create a loop that goes through each of the `am-event-info` divs, looks at the date and inserts another div within the `am-event-info` div that shows the day. e.g first `am-event-info` would have Saturday, second would have Sunday etc.

I have the code that shows the day and it only works for the first instance with the for loop but it keeps reapeting it self within the first instance. What can i do to rectify this?

```js
var day = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', {
        weekday: 'long'
      }).format(
        new Date(
       $(".am-event-info").forEach(function () {
       $(this).find('.am-event-sub-info:eq(1)').text().trim().split(' - ')[0].replace("th","") // only interested in the "February 27, 2021 11:30 am" part 
        }))
      )


                document.querySelector('.am-event-sub-info').innerHTML += '<div class="day">'+day+'</div>';
```

```css
.am-event-info {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1xp solid white;
  background: #c5c5c5;
  margin: 10px;
}

.day {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="am-events-booking">

  <div class="am-event-info">
    <div class="am-event-sub-info">
      <div class="am-event-sub-info-capacity"><img src=""> Capacity: 0 / 100</div>

    </div>
    <div class="am-event-sub-info">
      <div><img src="">February 27th, 2021 11:30 am - 1:00 pm</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="am-event-info">
    <div class="am-event-sub-info">
      <div class="am-event-sub-info-capacity"><img src=""> Capacity: 0 / 100</div>

    </div>
    <div class="am-event-sub-info">
      <div><img src="">February 28th, 2021 11:30 am - 1:00 pm</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="am-event-info">
    <div class="am-event-sub-info">
      <div class="am-event-sub-info-capacity"><img src=""> Capacity: 0 / 100</div>

    </div>
    <div class="am-event-sub-info">
      <div><img src="">March 1st, 2021 11:30 am - 1:00 pm</div>
    </div>
  </div>


</div>
```

Comment: because you need to loop over each timestamp... you do not magically get them all in one swipe. `$(".am-event-info").forEach(function () { $(this); //<--- that is the current element in the loop})`

Comment: thanks. Adding this i get the error `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).forEach is not a function`

Comment: @user38208 it's a typo/mixing jquery with js - use `.each` as in the provided answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop, you are only acting on the first index

```js
$(".am-event-info").each(function() {

  var subInfo = $(this);
  var timeString = subInfo.find('.am-event-sub-info:eq(1)').text().trim().split(' - ')[0].replace(/(th|st|nd|rd),/, ",");
  var date = new Date(timeString);

  var day = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', {
    weekday: 'long'
  }).format(date);

  subInfo.append('<div class="day">' + day + '</div>');

});
```

```css
.am-event-info {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1xp solid white;
  background: #c5c5c5;
  margin: 10px;
}

.day {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="am-events-booking">

  <div class="am-event-info">
    <div class="am-event-sub-info">
      <div class="am-event-sub-info-capacity"><img src=""> Capacity: 0 / 100</div>

    </div>
    <div class="am-event-sub-info">
      <div><img src="">February 27th, 2021 11:30 am - 1:00 pm</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="am-event-info">
    <div class="am-event-sub-info">
      <div class="am-event-sub-info-capacity"><img src=""> Capacity: 0 / 100</div>

    </div>
    <div class="am-event-sub-info">
      <div><img src="">February 28th, 2021 11:30 am - 1:00 pm</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="am-event-info">
    <div class="am-event-sub-info">
      <div class="am-event-sub-info-capacity"><img src=""> Capacity: 0 / 100</div>

    </div>
    <div class="am-event-sub-info">
      <div><img src="">March 1st, 2021 11:30 am - 1:00 pm</div>
    </div>
  </div>


</div>
```